# Saving out from a model in a for loop in r

Tags: r, loops

I have a dataframe like this one

```
  ourmodel difference new_topic
1        2 0.08233167         1
2        3 0.07837389         2
3        1 0.15904427         3
4        3 0.05716799         4
5        1 0.13388058         3
6        3 0.09156650         3
```

and I wish to save each output from the model in the variable `out`. My approach doesn't seem to work - can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?
This is how I do:

```
library(rethinking)

out <- list()

for (i in unique(singo$new_topic)) {
  i <- ulam(
    alist(
        difference ~ dnorm(mu, sigma),
        mu <- a[ourmodel],
        a[ourmodel] ~ dnorm(0.40, 0.15) ,
        sigma ~ dexp(2) 
    ), data = final, chains = 4, cores = 4)
  out[[i]] <- precis(i, depth = 2)
}
```

I get the following error

```
Error in out[[i]] <- precis(i, depth = 2) : invalid subscript type 'S4'
```

Comment: Create an empty list with predefined length: `out <- vector(mode = "list", length = length(unique(singo$new_topic)))`. Not sure if this will solve the issue, as I think the issue is in `precis`. Test it let us know.

Comment: Also, i variable is from forloop, then we are using i for output of ulam...

Comment: I've just tested it - it doesn't work. I'm also worried that the problem stems from precis. ----- I've tried to change i to z in the output without any results

Comment: You are overwriting "i". Use something else to hold the ulam output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're making 2 mistakes:

### 1. You are iterating across S4 objects, rather than integers.

Rather than

```r
for (i in unique(singo$new_topic))
```

You want

```r
max_i <- length(unique(singo$new_topic))
for (i in 1:max_i)
```

The error you are getting is because you are iterating over the elements of `singo` and trying to subset with them, rather than with an integer.

This example might make the nature of the error clearer:

```r
animals <- c("cow", "pig", "sheep")

## This works
for(i in 1:length(animals)){
  print(animals[[i]])
}
#> [1] "cow"
#> [1] "pig"
#> [1] "sheep"

## This also works
for(i in animals){
  print(i)
}
#> [1] "cow"
#> [1] "pig"
#> [1] "sheep"

## This does not
for(i in animals){
  print(animals[[i]])
}
#> Error in animals[[i]]: subscript out of bounds
```

<sup>Created on 2022-11-18 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

### 2. You are overwriting `i`

If you want to use `i` to subset your list, you should not overwrite the value of `i` in the first line of your list. So do something like:

```
for(i in 1:max_i){
## don't assign to i here:
j <- ulam(
## some code 
)

## Use i as the index, j as the first argument to precis()
out[[i]] <- precis(j, depth = 2)
}
```

### 3. Bonus: It's better to make an empty list of the correct lenght.

So try:

```r
out <- vector("list", length = max_i)
```

To initialise `out` before you run the for loop. This makes your code clearer and faster to run.